# How to remove blog name from post title in search engines

Tags: html, blogger

I have the blog in search engines with every post show me blog name at the end of posts title. I want to remove blog name at the end of each post title because I think it's a bad idea for SEO. this is my title code within my template.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    <title>
      <data:blog.pageName/>
      | 
      <data:blog.title/>
    </title>
    <b:else/>
    <title>
      <data:blog.pageTitle/>
      - CAD drawing library for engineers
    </title>
  </b:if>
  <b:else/>
  <title>
    <data:blog.pageName/>
    | 
    <data:blog.title/>
  </title>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Please check this link:-http://mybloggerexperience.blogspot.com/2009/03/remove-blog-title-from-post-title.html or link:-https://ukbloggersblog.blogspot.com/2012/10/remove-name-from-page-titles-seo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
    <title>
        <data:blog.title/>
    </title>
<b:else/>
    <title>
        <data:blog.pageName/>
    </title>
</b:if>
```